# How to convert a malformed plist into a list of pair in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: list, emacs

Let's say we have the following malformed plist

```
(defvar mplist '(
              :lang 'js 'html5 'css 'sass 
              :writing 'org 'markdown))
(defvar plist ())
```

The question is how to convert `mplist` into a `plist` for example

```
'(
 (:lang . 'js)
 (:lang . 'html5)
 (:lang . 'css)
 (:lang . 'sass)
 (:writing . 'org)
 (:writing . 'markdown))
```

My use case is to write a macro which is a wrapper of `use-package`, each package is installed based on each module/layers (like `spacemacs` or `doom-emacs`).

Your helps are appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example you used for a **[plist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Lists.html)** is actually an **[alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html)**.

```
'((:lang . 'js)
  (:lang . 'html5)
  (:lang . 'css)
  (:lang . 'sass)
  (:writing . 'org)
  (:writing . 'markdown))
```

To put it simply:

- A [plist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Lists.html) is a *flat* list of key->value pairs, e.g. `'(:a 1 :b 2 :c 3)`
- An [alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html) is a list of lists, whose car = the key and cdr = the value. `'((a . 1) (b . 2) (c . 3))`.

If you only intend to iterate over this list of pairs, phils answer is fine, but if your dataset isn't tiny (say, >40 entries) and you need to test for membership, i.e. "Is `:lang css` enabled?", consider using a [hash table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html).

Reason being, your keys aren't unique. `(assq :lang alist)` will yield `'(:lang . js)`. The rest are shadowed by this first match. With this alist your only choice is `member`:

```
(member '(:lang . css) alist)
```

But `member` is O(n). If you're fine with that, again, phils answer is what you need. If you aren't (e.g. you do lookups frequently), then either restructure the input to have unique, symbol keys (e.g. concatenate :lang and css into one symbol, like `:lang-css`) and use `assq` (still O(n), but faster), or use a [hash table](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hash-Tables.html) instead.

For a hash table we need to slightly modify phils' answer:

```
;; initialize the hash table if necessary
(unless table
  (setq table (make-hash-table :test #'equal)))

(let (pkey)
  (dolist (i mplist)
    (if (keywordp i)
        (setq pkey i)
      ;; (puthash KEY VALUE HASH-TABLE)
      (puthash (cons pkey i) t table))))
```

Then you can do an O(1) membership check with `(gethash '(:lang . css) table)` or iterate over pairs with `(maphash (lambda (pair _) [...]) table)`.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I expect the `keywordp` predicate is what you're looking for?

```el
(let (plist pkey)
  (dolist (i mplist (nreverse plist))
    (if (keywordp i)
        (setq pkey i)
      (push (cons pkey i) plist))))
```

Comment: tks u @phils, it makes sense to me!